# WebStorm React native Emmet expansion for styling

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webstorm

Is there anyway to use Emmet expansion for styles in RN project in WebStorm? Just like normal CSS.

Now when I'm styling a component and try to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> for a style in JSX file it only create a dummy HTML element instead of CSS.

For example:

```
button: {
    df \\here I click tab for "display:'flex'"
}
```

The result will be:

```
button: {
    <df></df>
}
```

While the preferred result is:

```
button: {
    display: 'flex'
}
```

I googled widely but didn't find any solution neither any complains, is it only me suffering for writing everything by hand instead of using tab?

Comment: please can you provide a full code snippet? Does it happen when editing StyleSheet definition (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html), or?

Comment: Yes when editing StyleSheet definition, like:
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    df \\here I click tab for "display:'flex'"
  }
});